Semantic security of ElGamal
On pages 9-11 of the paper Sequence of games, Shoup provides a detailed proof of the semantic security of a hashed EleGamal. However, he only claims security goals. I would like to know what the attack/adversary model is: EVA, CPA or CCA.

Does this answer your question? Easy explanation of "IND-" security notions?

The attacker model is given in the initial attack games. For hashed ElGamal, see Attack Game 0. Roughly, semantic security, as defined in Shoup's paper, is similar to CPA security because the attacker is not allowed to encrypt queries. In the PKE setting, these two notions are equivalent, although the advantages should account for the number of encryption queries.
As a side note, attacker capabilities are usually part of the security goals, namely whatever the security game defines. It's another question whether the security definition is then meaningful. However, it's possible to define security meaningfully without explicitly talking about “an adversary”.

About encryption queries, I am confused these days. Why encryption queries is provided in CCA models? If all cipher text  adversary accessed is from the queries. The challenge knows all cipher text  and corresponding plaintext. This is to say, the challenger is able to correctly response any decryption query by record.
